# HP Pavilion 27xi Monitor Driver

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-drivers

Where can I find a driver for this monitor for use on Ubuntu 16.04.2? I have looked all over the internet. Found one site that offered the driver but could not find anyway to download it (linux-drivers.net). HP only has drivers for Windows. I have Windows 10 Pro and it works with that as well as a VM of Windows 8.1 Pro. I just installed Ubuntu in a VM and need a driver for that. Thanks for any help.